# This python loop needs a fix

Tags: python, loops

So, I have this code:

```
path_list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
             'a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9',
             'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9',
             'c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9']

def grabber():

    a = 0
    max_path = 39
    path = path_list[int(a)]
    while a <= max_path:
        print(path)
        a = a+1
```

And when I run `grabber()`, It returns the same item, always.

So, running `grabber()` always return `0`, which is the first element of the `path_list`

So, how can I solve it? I really need this loop to change the item in the list.

Comment: You're only changing `path` *outside* the loop currently.

Comment: `grabber` returns only `None`

Comment: Yeah, actually that code isn't the full one, but I figured out how to solve. If all the stuff is inside the loop, it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop, it's much simpler:

```
path_list = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
             'a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'a7', 'a8', 'a9',
             'b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9',
             'c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9']

def grabber():
    for path in path_list:
        print(path)
```

or alternately:

```
def grabber():
    for i in range(len(path_list)):
        print(path_list[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `path = path_list[int(a)]` line inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks! That helped.